# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a local validation. Every combination you enter in editText1 (for example abc) should be converted to numbers (a=1, b=2, c=3). The text in editText2 should match abc converted to numbers (123). If this is true: start the new activity. else: display a 'login failed' textview.

```
 public class Login extends Activity {

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle(R.string.login);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_login);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton2);

    EditText email_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText code_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final String userEmail = email_text.getText().toString(); 
    final String userCode = code_text.getText().toString(); 
    String x = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        x += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i)); 
    }
    final int validCode = Integer.parseInt(x);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (userCode.equals(validCode)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginfailed);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editText2.setText("");
            }
        }

    });

}

private int getNumber(Character c) {
    return "abdcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(c) + 1;
}
```

However, when I run my app it crashes immediately and the following error raises:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:main 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {...}:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

how do i fix this??

Comment: which line does it throw the error on?

Comment: move the for loop inside button click. `userEmail.charAt(i)` userEmail is empty i guess

Comment: change to for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)

Comment: @RossDrew in the LogCat

Comment: @Raghunandan where in the button click? and what do you mean by saying userEmail is empty? For the user didn't even had a chance to fill in anything.

Comment: @YoranY you enter data in edittext and then click the button so move for loop inside `onClick`. move  `final String userEmail = email_text.getText().toString(); 
    final String userCode = code_text.getText().toString(); 
    String x = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        x += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i)); 
    }
    final int validCode = Integer.parseInt(x);` inside `onClick`

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you ? If yes then please accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of issues in your code:

- first, as noticed by many, you are looping through userEmail when it has not been initialised, because your edit texts are empty; move it to onClickListener;
- in onClickListener, check if userEmail and userCode are not empty and proceed only then, otherwise inform user to enter email and/or code
- inside your else statement, you can't directly use id to access editText2; since you already foundViewById, change:

  ```
  editText2.setText("");
  ```

  to

  ```
  code_text.setText("");
  ```
- in your loop, you have hardcoded the length, which will work for your sample 'abc' string, but won't as expected for longer strings; change it to:

  ```
  for(int i=0; i<userEmail.length(); i++)
  ```
- you are building your x String which you then use to create validCode; this will work fine for userEmail strings up to 10 characters long - it will fail for longer. Why? You are storing validCode in an integer variable, the maximum int is 2^31-1 (2147483647), which is 10 characters long. Change validCode to long, or even better...
- instead of changing to long, why don't you compare strings? Instead of introducing new variable, and converting x string to number, and since userCode is already a string, you can simply compare strings, co change String x = "" to:

  ```
  String validCode = "";

  if (userCode.equals(validCode)) {
      //rest of the code
  ```
- also, in your getNumber() method, your return statement is:

  ```
  return "abdcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".indexOf(c) + 1;
  ```

  Is "abdc..." intentional? Shouldn't it be "abcd.."? :)

See the code below with comments and modifications:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle(R.string.login);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_login);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton2);

        final EditText email_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText code_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //check if user entered email and code, continue only if they have
                if (email_text.getText().length() > 0 && code_text.getText().length() > 0) {
                    //moved here, to avoid exception when text boxes are empty
                    final String userEmail = email_text.getText().toString();
                    final String userCode = code_text.getText().toString();

                    //changed from String x = "" because userCode is already a String
                    //and we don't have to change x to int, because we can compare 
                    //strings
                    String validCode = "";

                    //don't hardcode stop condition for i,
                    //instead, use the length of user entered string
                    for (int i = 0; i < userEmail.length(); i++) {
                        validCode += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i));
                    }

                    //now we can compare userCode with validCode
                    if (userCode.equals(validCode)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loginfailed);
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        //reset string in code_text editText
                        code_text.setText("");
                    }
                }
                //userEmail or/and userCode text boxes are empty, inform user
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email and/or code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Wow it worked perfect for me! I added .toLowerCase() to improve the code and added ".", "@", "-" and "_" to getNumber. I still have a question. After that I made sure that the email adress box has to contain at least 5 chars. (to proceed to the next screen) I started messing up the validation codes (validCode += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i))*871; for example). Is there a way that the validation codes gets cut to a maximum of 10 digits? And so that it won't contain decimals?

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        x += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i)); 
 }
```

possibly before any data is entered. Move the for-loop inside  `public void onClick()` and always have a check to see if userEmail is not empty.

**Example**

```
if(code_text.getText().toString().Length() > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            x += getNumber(code_text.getText().toString().charAt(i)); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well when you initialize the app the the email_text probably doesn't have any text therefore you are getting an empty string that would have a length of 0. I believe you can improve the getnumber function by casting to an int and subtracting a fixed number.

```
return (int)c - fixedvalue;
```

See http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html for the int values for characters.

Answer (score 0):

Changes

```
userEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(userEmail.getText().length() > 0){
         for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
         x += getNumber(userEmail.charAt(i)); 
         }
         final int validCode = Integer.parseInt(x);
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
    });
```